# Error with data sets in BIRT

Tags: eclipse, grid, dataset, birt

I am eclipse 4.5 with BIRT feature enabled. I have inserted multiple grids and tables inside a single table. Each grid and the table inside the main table as some defined data sets.

But it show me that *table must able to access one data set*. My doubt is I have never given any dataset to the main table. Is this the error?

Answer (score 0):

A table MUST be bound to a data set. The table will instantiate one detail row per dataset record.

You can always use a dummy dataset like SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL (on Oracle) which returns a single row.

BRW what is the intention of your main table?
You should always use the appropriate BIRT layout item for the given task.